# What does the phrase "You have a mice nest in your mouth" mean

Tags: phrase-meaning

I was chatting with a colleague and she just said that I have a mice nest in my mouth, what does it mean?

Comment: Why didn't you ask her what she meant?

Comment: As a native English speaker, I have no idea what she meant. I can guess various possibilities, but it is not a phrase I recognise. (I also find _mice nest_ utterly unnatural as an English expression: I would expect _mouse's nest_ or _mouse nest_).

Comment: I've never heard the expression before. But if I had to guess, I'd say it meant that you had bad breath.